# SQL select rows where column contains any of word from string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with people holidays 'id', 'day', 'month', 'name'

```html
<table rules='all' border='black'>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>day</td>
            <td>month</td>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Adam</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Pavel a Petr</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I'm saving name from people holidays into `strtolower($name) => $name = Pavel a Petr`

And I have a table of users where name is `Pavel`

Now I need SQL query which can `select * from users where lower(name) contains '".$name."'`

I'm looking for SQL solution. 
If there is no SQL solution, can some one suggest me a php solution.

Thank you.

Comment: can you use      select * from users where name like %.$name.%     logic?

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to select if contains any word from string

Comment: Are you using FULL TEXT search ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [MySQL LIKE Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm)

E.g:

```
"select * from `users` where lower(name) LIKE '%$name%'"
```

If SQL LIKE clause is used along with % characters, then it will work like a meta character (*) in UNIX while listing out all the files or directories at command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) to pattern match.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%$name%';
```

The `%` is the wildcard operator, so this allows anything before or after the name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use REGEXP

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(name) RLIKE  "[[:<:]]$name[[:>:]]"
```

Comment: I will try, this option I didn't try.

Comment: Doesn't work...important is $name = Pavel a Petr and name column in user is Pavel

Comment: @user5366720 Your question is not clear to me. could you include a sample data and your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is this you are looking for:

EDIT: You should not have a user with the name "a"  :-)

EDIT2: Just found, that the sql-server tag is taken away...

```
DECLARE @peopleHolidays TABLE(id INT,day INT,month INT, name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @peopleHolidays VALUES(1,1,5,'Adam'),(2,2,5,'Pavel a Petr'),(2,3,5,'Adam a Max'),(2,4,5,'Max a Petr');

DECLARE @users TABLE(id INT IDENTITY,name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @users VALUES('Adam'),('Pavel'),('Petr'),('Max');

SELECT *
FROM @peopleHolidays AS pH
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(pH.name,' ','</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)) AS AsXml(x)
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM @users AS u
    WHERE u.name IN
    (
        SELECT a.b.value('.','varchar(max)')
        FROM AsXml.x.nodes('/r') AS a(b)
    )
) AS UsersInHoliday
```

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said, LIKE will give you a comparator for part of the string. You can use string concatenation for the like argument and therefore pass the string you're searching for safely and not at as much risk of SQL Injection

```
select * from users where name like '%' + :name + '%'
```

Use prepared statements in PHP;

[How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by PHP, not by SQL, code just looks like

```
function isClientInDb($name, $array){
        global $db;

        $name = strtolower($name);      

        $query = "SELECT * from `clients` where LOWER (name) = '".$name."' and `uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
        $result = $db->select($query);      
        if(count($result) < 1){

        if(intval(preg_match('/\s/',$name)) > 0){
            if(strpos($name, ",")){
                $pos = strpos($name, ",");      
                $minus = 1; 
            }else{
                if(strpos($name, "a")){
                $pos = strpos($name, "a");  
                $minus = 0;         
                }else{
                $pos = strpos($name, " ");
            }           
            }           
            $pole = array(strtolower(substr($name,0,$pos)), strtolower(substr($name,-($pos+$minus))));

            $sql = "lower(name) = '".$pole[0]."' or lower(name) = '".$pole[1]."'";              
            }else{
            $sql = "lower(name) LIKE '%".$name."%'";            
            }       

        $query = "SELECT * from `clients` where ( $sql ) and `uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
        $result = $db->select($query);
        if(count($result) < 1){
            return false;           
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }


        }else{
        return true;        
        }   
        }
```